# I'm working with Pandas in Python, and I cant understand why does 'x' is printed as 98 on this lambda expression

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, lambda

Why does the following line of code returns x as 98? I though x would assume every index value of df_refData. As an exemple, x return this on the first operation: {'10-20': 9.1, '0-10': 4.2, '20-30': 6}

```
df_refData['Cs/min - bruto'].apply(lambda x: print(x))
```

df_refData['Cs/min - bruto'] is setted up like this:

```
0               {'10-20': 9.1, '0-10': 4.2, '20-30': 6}
1     {'10-20': 1.1, '0-10': 0.30000000000000004, '3...
2             {'10-20': 7.199999999999999, '0-10': 6.5}
3             {'10-20': 6.800000000000001, '0-10': 8.3}
4     {'10-20': 8.1, '0-10': 6.5, '30-end': 3.2, '20...
5            {'10-20': 0.8999999999999999, '0-10': 0.4}
6              {'10-20': 0.6000000000000001, '0-10': 0}
7     {'10-20': 1.8, '0-10': 0.30000000000000004, '2...
8     {'10-20': 1.1, '0-10': 0.2, '30-end': 1.2, '20...
9               {'10-20': 0.2, '0-10': 0, '20-30': 1.7}
10                          {'10-20': 1.6, '0-10': 0.2}
11                            {'10-20': 5.5, '0-10': 5}
12              {'10-20': 3, '0-10': 0.1, '20-30': 0.3}
13                          {'10-20': 1.1, '0-10': 0.3}
14                                        {'0-10': 0.2}
15                          {'10-20': 4.3, '0-10': 6.1}
16    {'10-20': 1.1, '0-10': 0.6, '30-end': 2.4, '20...
Name: Cs/min - bruto, dtype: object
```

Comment: "Why does the following line of code returns x as 98?" where you getting 98? the data you posted doesn't contain 98?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @deadshot That's what I am saying, the value 98 is not even in the dict

Comment: Guys, nvm... I'm was already using the variable 'x' in another part of my code, i thought lambda expression variable was local, therefore wouldn't be a problem to use 'x' again.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to print the dataframe part of 'Cs/min - bruto'? if yes, have you tried:

```
print(df_refData['Cs/min - bruto'].tostring())
```

Comment: Actually I want to do something else in the lambda expression, but I was getting some problems and decided to use de print() function to investigate what was happening and got this 98 value for x

Comment: oh ok, then maybe its best to explain what exactly you are trying to do and hopefully we can help you out.